# Как нажать сквозь окно?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi

Есть окно WPF. Нужно, чтобы щелчок мыши по окну передался под (за) окно. То есть не важно, что там под окном, другое окно, голый рабочий стол или еще что. Должен сгенерироваться щелчок мыши как бы сквозь окно. При этом само окно должно остаться сверху. Возможно оно вообще TopMost. Это возможно? Как?

Comment: Может [SetCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) вам поможет? ("Мышиный" фокус ввода, в функцию передаётся handle окна, которое примет ближайшее мышиное событие)

Comment: @nick_n_a, не понимаю как его использовать в данном случае. Это же еще нужно узнать что за окно находится за моим окном под курсором. К тому же там вообще может не быть окна

Comment: Если вы хотите "дырявое" окно, то вам нужна функция [SetWindowRgn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd145102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и создать "регион" нужной формы [Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) а для c# [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.region%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @nick_n_a, а можно подробнее?

Comment: Вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread246583.html более менее вменяемый пример (внизу). Тут https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291/Creating-holes-in-a-window картинка с результатом хорошая.

Comment: @nick_n_a, понятно. Это не мой случай. Дыра мне не нужна. Окно, конечно, будет полупрозрачным, но с наполнением, и дыры там недопустимы

Comment: @iRumba: Может быть, это подойдёт: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1524035/276994?

Comment: @VladD, очень может быть. Проверю позже

Answer (score 0):

Если такое поведение нужно безусловно, для этого элемента IsHitTestVisible="False" , делая его "невидимым" для мыши.

Это это предполагает какое-то управление,  то такое поведение называется event propagation в общем случае, в случае WFP - маршрутизация событий (event routing, термин пришедший из MFC). Например, есть события Preview***  где при изменении флага Handled в RoutedEventArgs  можно отключить остановить прохождение события.

О маршрутизации событий: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx

Comment: Вообще то окно не получается при этом сквозным

Comment: @iRumba в котором случае и поясните свой термин "сквозной". Если "не получать события" - то это IsHitTestVisible. Если нужно обрабатывать и передавать далее, то надо делать марштизацию, соответствующу необходимой схеме

Comment: @Swift: имеется в виду, судя по всему, чтобы _всё_ окно было прозрачным для мышиных событий, т. е., клик передавался _другому окну_.

Comment: @VladD, да, вы правы. Причем я именно так и написал. Может у вас есть идеи, как такое осуществить?

Comment: @iRumba: Думаю, нужны упомянутые в комментариях регионы.